# It is safe to save comments of users with out checking with : mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php

I just want to confirm it because mysql make some changes in comment like image HTML it add `\"` I know its making it secure but can you suggest me? I am first saving it to database and then display it in comments box.

**I am using :**

```
if (isset($_POST['comment-post'])) {
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    if ($id != "" && strlen(trim(preg_replace('/\xc2\xa0/',' ',$comment))) != 0) {
        $add = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET comments='$comment' WHERE id='$id'");
    }
}
```

**Or should i use this :**

```
if (isset($_POST['comment-post'])) {
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
    if ($id != "" && strlen(trim(preg_replace('/\xc2\xa0/',' ',$comment))) != 0) {
        $add = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET comments='$comment' WHERE id='$id'");
    }
}
```

**Example of comment user can post is:**

```
Hello how are you?
<img src="http://i840.photobucket.com/albums/zz324/wonderfulworld1/Hearts/rt28h.gif">
```

Comment: Its never ever safe to just replace that character and leave the rest as is, its always a better idea to sanitize properly. However the concept of string interpolation in queries using `mysql_*` extension is itself becoming obsolete by the minute, move on to `mysqli` or `PDO` and use prepared statements.

Comment: Yes its getting harder and harder to handle MySQL_ well thanks i will try my best to upgrade it to mysqli which will not take much time for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recomend stop using Mysql_* functions, they are deprecated and will be gone from PHP in later versions.

Check out PDO or Mysqli, both of those have prepared statements, which will help you with this kind of issues.

Comment: Yes i will be using 'Mysqli_' soon.

Comment: Soon is not soon enough :)

Comment: Then use prepared statements and you will be safe, no need to escape the string or anything.

Comment: Really no need to escape or anything like that in mysqli_ ?

Comment: Not with prepared statements. No. Just using mysqli_query() will be practically the same as mysql_query() and requires the same type of safety checks and escapes.
When/If printing it (which i guess you will), it might be a good idea to use htmlspecialchars or similar tho.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe.
The code you posted is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), when running the query, and Cross-site scripting when the comment is shown on your pages.

You should always filter user input by escaping it using `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `strip_tags` (or `filter_var`) functions.

Comment: Note that `mysqli_real_escape_string` doesn’t work with the MySQL extension.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_eascape_string protects against SQL inection attacks, but doesn't sanitise the data against other possible attacks. The same is true for prepared statements. If you're using `mysql` you should escape your data properly.

However, if you're displaying user data you need to ensure that the data you are displayng is also clean. You must protect agains tags like `<script></script>` appearing unsanitised in your output stream.